# How can I make Matlab recognize a time-delay system as symbolic?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

How can I make Matlab recognize a time-delay system as symbolic? I have:

```
syms t x y     % which should declare x & y as functions of t
X = [x; t]     % which are the variables of my system
IC = [x0; y0]  % which are the initial conditions of my system

prog = sosprogram(X);
vec = monomials(X, 0:1:4);
[prog, V] = sospolyvar(prog, vec, 'wscoeff');
prog = sosineq(prog, V);

dx = -2*x(t) - x(t-T);     % where T is the constant delay
dy = -y(t) - x(t-T) - y(t-T);
D = [dx; dy];     % my system

Vd = -diff(V,x)*D(1) - diff(V,y)*D(2);
```

If I make a separate function handle according to the dde23 help page, where

```
D = @systemFunction;
```

then my script breaks at determining Vd and outputs an Error: Not enough input arguments (which I understand and want to do away with the function handle). But if I do away with the function handles and make systemFunction

```
dx = -2*x(t) - x(t-T);     % where T is the constant delay
dy = -y(t) - x(t-T) - y(t-T);
D = [dx; dy];     % my system
```

then it breaks because MATLAB won't recognize y(t-T) as the symbolic function y(t) with some delay T added. Is there anyway I can change this? I don't want to solve the system, but find a Lyapunov for it using SOSTools.

My error message is:

```
Error using systemFunction.
Not enough input arguments.
Error in Script (line 50)
Vd = -diff(V,x).*D(1)-diff(V,y).*D(2);
```

I know why I get this error. It's because I'm trying to call systemFunction without giving it all the relevant bits. So I want to do away with that. In order to do that, I need to know how to symbolically represent y(t-T) as y(t) with some delay T added.

Edit: Added the relevant code and some additional explanation.

Comment: Post the code you have implemented and produces the error.

Comment: I just did.  Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: What are the `sosprogram`, `monomials`, `sospolyvar` and `sosineq` functions? And are they compatible with symbolic inputs? You also mentioned `ode23` but there is no call to `ode23` in the code you gave?

Comment: @David I mentioned dde23.  Initially I was using dde23 to solve the system, but took that out because it wasn't contributing anything to my goal.  The other functions mentioned are compatible with symbolic inputs.  They're part of a matlab toolbox built by some people at CalTech.  I've used them before with symbolic input.

Comment: Read and post the full error message, they are useful.

Comment: @David I'm not sure how useful it'll be in this case, but I've added it to my post.

Comment: Do you expect `D=[dx;dy]` to do the same as `D=@systemFunction`?